# Table is not reflecting updated row on vf page

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class, table

i am deleting my attachments records and after deleting them the page gets refresh but the row is still available in table. But if i manually refresh my page using F5 button then it reflects correctly. can anyone suggest me how to resolve this ?

```
VF Page:-
<apex:page controller="Test">
```

```
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Save"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>

  <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1" >

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="File Name" for="fileName"/>
      <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file"/>
      <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="Description" for="description"/>
      <apex:inputTextarea value="{!attachment.description}" id="description"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

  </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock Title="Delete" rendered="{!flag}">
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <apex:commandButton value="Delete Selected" action="{!processSelected}" />
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listw}" var="a" >                    
               <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}"/>
               </apex:column>
               <apex:column value="{!a.att.name}"/>
                <apex:column title="Image">
                 <apex:image url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!a.att.id}" height="100" width="100"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Controller:-

```
public with sharing class Test {

public Id accountid{get; set;}
public List<wrapperAtt> listw {get; set;}
public boolean flag{get; set;}

public List<Attachment> getAttachments(){
        return [SELECT id FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId=:accid];
    }
public void parentAccountid()
{  
  flag = false;
  listw = new List<wrapperAtt>();
  List<Account> accList = [Select id from Account where Name = 'Trying'];
  if(!accList.isEmpty()){
    accid = accList[0].id; 
    }
   else
   {
     Account acc = new Account();
     acc.Name = 'Trying';
     insert acc;
     List<Account> accList1 = [Select id from Account where Name = 'Trying'];
     accid = accList1[0].id; 
   }
   list<attachment> att = [select id, name, body from Attachment where parentId =:accid ];

        for(attachment at : att)
        {
            listw.add(new wrapperAtt(at));
        } 
}

public Attachment attachment {
  get {
      if (attachment == null)
        attachment = new Attachment();
      return attachment;
    }
  set;
  }



  public PageReference upload() {

    attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    attachment.ParentId = accid; // the record the file is attached to
    attachment.IsPrivate = true;

    try {
      insert attachment;
    } catch (DMLException e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
      return null;
    } finally {
      attachment = new Attachment(); 
    }
    listw.add(new wrapperAtt(attachment));
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));
    return null;
  }

   public PageReference processSelected() {

        List<Attachment> lstAttToDelete = new List<Attachment>();
        for(wrapperAtt wAtt: listw) 
        {
            if(wAtt.selected  == true)
            {
                lstAttToDelete.add(wAtt.att);

            }
        }

        if(lstAttToDelete.size() > 0 )
        {
            Delete lstAttToDelete;
        }
      return null;
   }
    public class wrapperAtt
    {
        public Attachment att {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public wrapperAtt(Attachment a) 
        {
            att = a;
            selected = false;

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listw wrapper list is being used for showing the data and lstAttToDelete being used to delete the data you need to do something to refresh the listw list so that it won't show the deleted data. call parentAccountid() method after Delete lstAttToDelete; statement to reflect updated data.

```
public with sharing class Test {

public Id accountid{get; set;}
public List<wrapperAtt> listw {get; set;}
public boolean flag{get; set;}

public List<Attachment> getAttachments(){
        return [SELECT id FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId=:accid];
    }
public void parentAccountid()
{  
  flag = false;
  listw = new List<wrapperAtt>();
  List<Account> accList = [Select id from Account where Name = 'Trying'];
  if(!accList.isEmpty()){
    accid = accList[0].id; 
    }
   else
   {
     Account acc = new Account();
     acc.Name = 'Trying';
     insert acc;
     List<Account> accList1 = [Select id from Account where Name = 'Trying'];
     accid = accList1[0].id; 
   }
   list<attachment> att = [select id, name, body from Attachment where parentId =:accid ];

        for(attachment at : att)
        {
            listw.add(new wrapperAtt(at));
        } 
}

public Attachment attachment {
  get {
      if (attachment == null)
        attachment = new Attachment();
      return attachment;
    }
  set;
  }



  public PageReference upload() {

    attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    attachment.ParentId = accid; // the record the file is attached to
    attachment.IsPrivate = true;

    try {
      insert attachment;
    } catch (DMLException e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
      return null;
    } finally {
      attachment = new Attachment(); 
    }
    listw.add(new wrapperAtt(attachment));
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));
    return null;
  }

   public PageReference processSelected() {

        List<Attachment> lstAttToDelete = new List<Attachment>();
        for(wrapperAtt wAtt: listw) 
        {
            if(wAtt.selected  == true)
            {
                lstAttToDelete.add(wAtt.att);

            }
        }

        if(lstAttToDelete.size() > 0 )
        {
            Delete lstAttToDelete;
            parentAccountid();
        }
      return null;
   }
    public class wrapperAtt
    {
        public Attachment att {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public wrapperAtt(Attachment a) 
        {
            att = a;
            selected = false;

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely related to cache. Default cache setting for Visualforce pages is 600 seconds and I've noticed that sometimes the browser (especially Chrome tends to use cache). You can verify this by looking at the Network tab in Developer Tools in the browser and see if it loads by cache. See http://www.verticalcoder.com/2017/05/10/chrome-and-public-sites-caching/

Try changing it to `<apex:page cache="false" controller="Test">`